# regex for getting path and filename from string in linux

Tags: regex, linux, path, filenames

In bash I would like to get filename from a command line string. But not the current ($0) script!

**I have a file full of scripts with parameters. I need just the scripts from it!**

For example i have a string like:
/path/to/file parameter1 -p2

i would like to get: /path/to/file (without the parameters)
even in cases:

```
/an\ example/with.dot.in_it/.hidden_file.sh par\ ameter1 p.dot.2
./script.sh p1 p2
../script.sh p1 p2
/any////relative/../path/./to/script.sh p1 p2
```

So in any valid linux path and filename cases!

Is there a regex for this purpose, or is there any other way to get this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily do it using the "cut" command and getting the first field as follows :   echo "$str" | cut -d " " -f1

Comment: No, if won't tackle if it has spaces. `$cut -d " " -f -2` is to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl's command line regex feature combined with readlink command to **always** get full path to your script. Let's data is your file name with all the command and their parameters. You can use script like this to get full path of your scripts:

```
while read -r F
do
    SCRIPT=$(perl -pe 's/^(.*?)(?<!\\) .*$/\1/;s/\\//g' <<< $F)
    readlink -f "$SCRIPT"
done < data
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm cannot use $0 here! And the script might be not existent on this computer!

Comment: That was an example. You can always do something like `echo $(readlink -f ../script.sh)`

Comment: `readlink -f "/asd/qwe/../zxc/./script.sh par1 par2"`
Result for this is nothing... but it should return `/asd/qwe/../zxc/./script.sh`

Comment: You should be getting error with above command of yours. Please understand that `readlink -f ` expects only 1 argument and that should be your script's name OR full path OR relative path or symlink etc. Your correct command would be: `readlink -f "/asd/qwe/../zxc/./script.sh"`

Comment: OK, but my problem is to remove the parameters from the string and then check that this is a valid path and filename in linux context!

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the shell or shell script from inside `.hidden_file.sh` you could use `$0`:

```
echo "$0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dirname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) command.

Comment: This prints just the directory name without the filename... but for paths it quite good!

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use regular expressions (many better solutions were discribed above) then this might help you:

```
/^(.+[^\\]) /
```

this matches all characters up to the first space, which doesn't follow a \

you get the path from the captured group

Answer (score 0):

```
basename "$string"
```

Or

```
${string##*/}
```